# association query issue

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I'm using mybatis , I encounter a association query issue, pls take a look at table structures first.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comp_items_spec`;

CREATE TABLE `comp_items_spec` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `in_list_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `static_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext1_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext1_value` text,
  `ext2_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext2_value` text,
  `ext3_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext3_value` text,
  `ext4_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext4_value` text,
  `ext5_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext5_value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `comp_items_spec` */

insert  into `comp_items_spec`(`id`,`comp_id`,`content_type_id`,`in_list_flag`,`label`,`static_flag`,`ext1_name`,`ext1_value`,`ext2_name`,`ext2_value`,`ext3_name`,`ext3_value`,`ext4_name`,`ext4_value`,`ext5_name`,`ext5_value`) values (43,22,1,'\0','description','Y','description','description1......',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),(44,22,3,'\0','static image','Y',NULL,'http://img3.cache.netease.com/cnews/2012/12/6/20121206092637ba11c.jpg',NULL,'501',NULL,'425',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

/*Table structure for table `components_spec` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `components_spec`;

CREATE TABLE `components_spec` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_latest_num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `more_link_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `more_link_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_in_new_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_sso` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updator_sso` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `components_spec` */

insert  into `components_spec`(`id`,`name`,`show_latest_num`,`more_link_url`,`more_link_flag`,`open_in_new_flag`,`create_date`,`update_date`,`creator_sso`,`updator_sso`) values (22,'Banner',5,'more.blog.ge.com','Y','Y','2012-12-08 21:30:58','2012-12-08 21:30:58','502156886','502156886');
```

the relationship between components_spec and comp_items_spec is 1:N,comp_items_spec has two kind of data ,dynamic items and static items which are distinguish from column static_flag, it's dynamic items when static_flag='N', and I also define bean ComponentSpec and CompItemSpec to map the entity. pls see the source code from below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ComponentSpec {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int showLatestNum;
    private String moreLinkUrl;
    private char moreLinkFlag;
    private char openInNewFlag;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private String creatorSSO;
    private String updatorSSO;
    private List<CompItemSpec> staticItemSpecList =new ArrayList<CompItemSpec>();
    private List<CompItemSpec> dynamicItemSpecList =new ArrayList<CompItemSpec>();

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public char getMoreLinkFlag() {
        return moreLinkFlag;
    }

    public void setMoreLinkFlag(char moreLinkFlag) {
        this.moreLinkFlag = moreLinkFlag;
    }

    public String getMoreLinkUrl() {
        return moreLinkUrl;
    }

    public void setMoreLinkUrl(String moreLinkUrl) {
        this.moreLinkUrl = moreLinkUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getShowLatestNum() {
        return showLatestNum;
    }

    public void setShowLatestNum(int showLatestNum) {
        this.showLatestNum = showLatestNum;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    public char getOpenInNewFlag() {
        return openInNewFlag;
    }

    public void setOpenInNewFlag(char openInNewFlag) {
        this.openInNewFlag = openInNewFlag;
    }

    public List<CompItemSpec> getStaticItemSpecList() {
        return staticItemSpecList;
    }

    public void addStaticItemSpec(CompItemSpec compStaticItemSpec){
        getStaticItemSpecList().add(compStaticItemSpec);
        compStaticItemSpec.setComponentSpec(this);
    }

    public List<CompItemSpec> getDynamicItemSpecList() {
        return dynamicItemSpecList;
    }

    public void addDynamicItemSpec(CompItemSpec dynamicItemSpec){
        getDynamicItemSpecList().add(dynamicItemSpec);
        dynamicItemSpec.setComponentSpec(this);
    }

    public String getCreatorSSO() {
        return creatorSSO;
    }

    public void setCreatorSSO(String creatorSSO) {
        this.creatorSSO = creatorSSO;
    }

    public String getUpdatorSSO() {
        return updatorSSO;
    }

    public void setUpdatorSSO(String updatorSSO) {
        this.updatorSSO = updatorSSO;
    }


}

public class CompItemSpec {
    private int id;
    private int compId;
    private int contentTypeId;
    private char inListFlag;
    private char staticFlag;
    private String label;
    private String ext1Name;
    private String ext1Value;
    private String ext2Name;
    private String ext2Value;
    private String ext3Name;
    private String ext3Value;
    private String ext4Name;
    private String ext4Value;
    private String ext5Name;
    private String ext5Value;
    private ComponentSpec componentSpec;

    public int getCompId() {
        return compId;
    }

    public void setCompId(int compId) {
        this.compId = compId;
    }

    public String getExt1Name() {
        return ext1Name;
    }

    public void setExt1Name(String ext1Name) {
        this.ext1Name = ext1Name;
    }

    public String getExt1Value() {
        return ext1Value;
    }

    public void setExt1Value(String ext1Value) {
        this.ext1Value = ext1Value;
    }

    public String getExt2Name() {
        return ext2Name;
    }

    public void setExt2Name(String ext2Name) {
        this.ext2Name = ext2Name;
    }

    public String getExt2Value() {
        return ext2Value;
    }

    public void setExt2Value(String ext2Value) {
        this.ext2Value = ext2Value;
    }

    public String getExt3Name() {
        return ext3Name;
    }

    public void setExt3Name(String ext3Name) {
        this.ext3Name = ext3Name;
    }

    public String getExt3Value() {
        return ext3Value;
    }

    public void setExt3Value(String ext3Value) {
        this.ext3Value = ext3Value;
    }

    public String getExt4Name() {
        return ext4Name;
    }

    public void setExt4Name(String ext4Name) {
        this.ext4Name = ext4Name;
    }

    public String getExt4Value() {
        return ext4Value;
    }

    public void setExt4Value(String ext4Value) {
        this.ext4Value = ext4Value;
    }

    public String getExt5Name() {
        return ext5Name;
    }

    public void setExt5Name(String ext5Name) {
        this.ext5Name = ext5Name;
    }

    public String getExt5Value() {
        return ext5Value;
    }

    public void setExt5Value(String ext5Value) {
        this.ext5Value = ext5Value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getContentTypeId() {
        return contentTypeId;
    }

    public void setContentTypeId(int contentTypeId) {
        this.contentTypeId = contentTypeId;
    }

    public char getInListFlag() {
        return inListFlag;
    }

    public void setInListFlag(char inListFlag) {
        this.inListFlag = inListFlag;
    }

    public char getStaticFlag() {
        return staticFlag;
    }

    public void setStaticFlag(char staticFlag) {
        this.staticFlag = staticFlag;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public ComponentSpec getComponentSpec() {
        return componentSpec;
    }

    public void setComponentSpec(ComponentSpec componentSpec) {
        this.componentSpec = componentSpec;
    }
}
```

sqlmap is like below:

```
    <mapper namespace="com.ge.dao.ComponentSpecMapper">
<resultMap id="componentMap" type="componentSpec">
    <id column="id" property="id"/>
    <result column="temp_id" property="tempId"/>
    <result column="show_latest_num" property="showLatestNum"/>
    <result column="more_link_url" property="moreLinkUrl"/>
    <result column="more_link_flag" property="moreLinkFlag"/>
    <result column="open_in_new_flag" property="openInNewFlag"/>
    <result column="update_date" property="updateDate"/>
    <result column="create_date" property="createDate"/>
    <result column="updator_sso" property="updatorSSO"/>
    <result column="creator_sso" property="creatorSSO"/>
    <collection property="staticItemSpecList" ofType="itemSpec">
        <id column="static_item_id" property="id"/>
        <result column="id" property="compId"/>
        <result column="static_content_type_id" property="contentTypeId"/>
        <result column="static_label" property="label"/>
        <result column="static_ext1_value" property="ext1Value"/>
        <result column="static_ext2_value" property="ext2Value"/>
        <result column="static_ext3_value" property="ext3Value"/>
        <result column="static_ext4_value" property="ext4Value"/>
        <result column="static_ext5_value" property="ext5Value"/>
    </collection>
    <collection property="dynamicItemSpecList" ofType="itemSpec">
        <id column="dynamic_item_id" property="id"/>
        <result column="id" property="compId"/>
        <result column="dynamic_content_type_id" property="contentTypeId"/>
        <result column="dynamic_in_list_flag" property="inListFlag"/>
        <result column="dynamic_label" property="label"/>
        <result column="dynamic_ext1_value" property="ext1Value"/>
        <result column="dynamic_ext2_value" property="ext2Value"/>
        <result column="dynamic_ext3_value" property="ext3Value"/>
        <result column="dynamic_ext4_value" property="ext4Value"/>
        <result column="dynamic_ext5_value" property="ext5Value"/>
    </collection>

</resultMap>

<sql id="compSpecMain">
      SELECT
          comp.id,
          comp.name,
          show_latest_num,
          more_link_url,
          more_link_flag,
          open_in_new_flag,
          create_date,
          update_date,
          creator_sso,
          updator_sso,
          si.id static_item_id,
          si.content_type_id static_content_type_id,
          si.in_list_flag static_in_list_flag,
          si.label static_label,
          si.ext1_value static_ext1_value,
          si.ext2_value static_ext2_value,
          si.ext3_value static_ext3_value,
          si.ext4_value static_ext4_value,
          si.ext5_value static_ext5_value,
          di.id dynamic_item_id,
          di.content_type_id dynamic_content_type_id,
          di.in_list_flag dynamic_in_list_flag,
          di.label dynamic_label,
          di.ext1_value dynamic_ext1_value,
          di.ext2_value dynamic_ext2_value,
          di.ext3_value dynamic_ext3_value,
          di.ext4_value dynamic_ext4_value,
          di.ext5_value dynamic_ext5_value
        FROM components_spec comp
            LEFT JOIN comp_items_spec si ON si.comp_id=comp.id AND si.static_flag='Y'
            LEFT JOIN comp_items_spec di ON di.comp_id=comp.id AND di.static_flag='N'
</sql>

<select id="selectComponentSpecByID" parameterType="int" resultMap="componentMap">
        <include refid="compSpecMain"/>
        WHERE
            comp.id=#{id}
</select>

 <select id="selectComponentSpecByName" parameterType="string" resultMap="componentMap">
        <include refid="compSpecMain"/>
        WHERE
            comp.name like #{name}

</select>
```

the issue here is when I do the selectComponentSpecByID query, the dynamic item list is supposed has nothing , but actual result is two elements, I think it's a problem with result map definition, but no glue. any suggestions? thanks .

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the solution by myself, because when id property is null ,meaning no records retrieved in the result, mybatis still compare them and treat them as valid result and put them into sub list,that's the reason, to fix it,just define notNullColumn of Collection element preventing null id. Done!

```
 <resultMap id="componentMap" type="componentSpec">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
        <result column="temp_id" property="tempId"/>
        <result column="show_latest_num" property="showLatestNum"/>
        <result column="more_link_url" property="moreLinkUrl"/>
        <result column="more_link_flag" property="moreLinkFlag"/>
        <result column="open_in_new_flag" property="openInNewFlag"/>
        <result column="update_date" property="updateDate"/>
        <result column="create_date" property="createDate"/>
        <result column="updator_sso" property="updatorSSO"/>
        <result column="creator_sso" property="creatorSSO"/>
        <collection property="staticItemSpecList" notNullColumn="static_item_id" ofType="itemSpec">
            <id column="static_item_id" property="id"/>
            <result column="id" property="compId"/>
            <result column="static_content_type_id" property="contentTypeId"/>
            <result column="static_label" property="label"/>
            <result column="static_ext1_value" property="ext1Value"/>
            <result column="static_ext2_value" property="ext2Value"/>
            <result column="static_ext3_value" property="ext3Value"/>
            <result column="static_ext4_value" property="ext4Value"/>
            <result column="static_ext5_value" property="ext5Value"/>
        </collection>
        <collection property="dynamicItemSpecList" notNullColumn="dynamic_item_id" ofType="itemSpec">
            <id column="dynamic_item_id" property="id"/>
            <result column="id" property="compId"/>
            <result column="dynamic_content_type_id" property="contentTypeId"/>
            <result column="dynamic_in_list_flag" property="inListFlag"/>
            <result column="dynamic_label" property="label"/>
            <result column="dynamic_ext1_value" property="ext1Value"/>
            <result column="dynamic_ext2_value" property="ext2Value"/>
            <result column="dynamic_ext3_value" property="ext3Value"/>
            <result column="dynamic_ext4_value" property="ext4Value"/>
            <result column="dynamic_ext5_value" property="ext5Value"/>
        </collection>

    </resultMap>
```